# Get all the items which are under one Cluster

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using android-maps-utils library.
I want to get all the items which is inside one cluster. i.e When one cluster is clicked, I want to have all the lat and long positions that contain in that cluster.
Here is an Image..

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/images/utility-markercluster.png

What I want is When I click 50+, I want to get all the lat long by which it is formed

When I add the lat long position, I do

```
   mClusterManager.addItem(new MyItem(lat,long)); //Here MyItem implements ClusterItem
```

What I want is

```
@Override
public boolean onClusterClick(Cluster<MyItem> cluster) {
    //Some method which can give all the lat long constitutes this cluster

    return true;
}
```

Comment: What did you try and where did you have problems?

Comment: Cluster Manager uses an algorithm and we cannot access the methods inside. Believe me I did everything I could. I don't know what next.

Comment: I have edited the question. Please see the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out

```
cluster.getItems()
```

or

```
new ArrayList<>(cluster.getItems())
```

It gives you an array list with your Objects you used while creating the cluster.